# vi shows as vim

Tags: vim

When I type `vi` into a terminal it shows the following display:

[image: vi]

Note that it says vim not vi, I'm sure I haven't downloaded vim yet and that this is actually vi not vim: for example the arrow keys print ABCD instead of moving.

Comment: It easy to check `update-alternatives --display vi`

Comment: Or `readlink -e $(which vi)` for non-debian distros

Comment: Gotta agree w/ Random832 re: the ABCD arrow keys thing is a tangential issue.  I've never seen vim behave that way.

Comment: @goldilocks I consistently get this behavior (on certain terminals, anyway) from "tiny/basic" versions of vim and not from the full version on the same systems. I suspect there's some compilation option that's disabled in the tiny versions that makes it work differently.

Comment: If it quacks like a vim, it *is* a vim. :-)

Comment: @Random832 terminfo support, I believe.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you are using Debian then `vi` is opening as `vim` because of the entry of `vi` in `/etc/alternatives`. Let me break this up for you.

When you do `ls -l /usr/bin/vi`:

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 20 Jul  1  2014 /usr/bin/vi -> /etc/alternatives/vi
```

As you can see the `vi` binary is a symbolic link to `/etc/alternatives/vi`.

Now if you do `ls -l /etc/alternatives/vi`:

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 18 Jul  1  2014 /etc/alternatives/vi -> /usr/bin/vim.basic
```

It's a symbolic link to the binary of `vim.basic`.

So, in a nutshell: `/usr/bin/vi` → `/etc/alternatives/vi` → `/usr/bin/vim.basic`

As a result if you type `vi` in the shell, `vim.basic` will open.

You can check and change the values in the `/etc/alternatives` by the command `update-alternatives` but I think your original question is already answered.

Answer (score 26):

While the original `vi` is [still available](http://ex-vi.sourceforge.net/), I do not think it is much used on current linux or BSD distributions;<sup>1</sup> apparently it was dusted off in 2000 after having been mothballed a decade before that, and the last release was 2005.

There are various *implementations* of vi around, which is really now a [POSIX specification](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/vi.html). These include `nvi` and `elvis`, but the most popular is probably `vim`.

On systems that use vim, `vi` will simply be a softlink to it and when invoked this way it should start in vi-compatible mode, so the system has something that conforms to the POSIX spec.  However, that doesn't change the actual name of the program, which is vim, and that's what you see on the title screen.

---

<sup>1.  Although it is [available on Arch](https://www.archlinux.org/packages/core/i686/vi/), at least.  You might find it other places too.</sup>

Comment: Arch Linux has this `vi` by default.

Comment: @Renan So it is; edited.

Comment: @Renan, pedantry: Arch Linux installs no application by default. `Vi` is part of the "base" group, which most people will select, but the Arch install process does not force you to install it.

Answer (score 8):

On many Linux systems, the default `vi` really is a version of Vim, typically one compiled with fewer options (no built-in perl and python support, no GUI, etc) than the one you would get if you installed a Vim package.

> for example the arrow keys print ABCD instead of moving.

This is caused by an inconsistency between your terminal emulator and Vim's understanding of the terminfo/termcap entry being used. Generally, it is caused by Vim having sent the `t_ks` code to "enable" the arrow keys (actually puts them in a mode where they send `<1b>OA` instead of `<1b>[A`) but the expected keys are for the other mode (e.g. `t_ku=<1b>[A` for up arrow). Try changing your TERM environment variable or vim option (`set term=builtin_ansi` or `builtin_xterm` in vimrc might work, though it may disable color), using a different terminal, or as a last resort adding `set t_ks= t_ke=` to your `.vimrc` file to disable this mode switching. This is a suggested solution in vim's help files, the next paragraph after `:help cs7-problem`.

This behavior is *not* in any way a sign that it is "actually vi not vim" - most modern "genuine" versions of vi or nvi also support the arrow keys.

Answer (score 5):

The original question has already been answered explaining that vi is an alias for vim, and that it is normal for the command vi to start vim.

What should be noted is that vim is (in some setups) sensitive to which name it is called by. Even though `vi` and `vim` both execute the same binary they can behave differently.

Answer (score 2):

Anyway, `vim` is a superset of `vi`. Meaning, everything that works in `vi` works in `vim`. For all intents and purposes, it is a more extensible version of `vi`.

> for example the arrow keys print ABCD instead of moving.

There are 2 solutions to this.

- Change your terminals character encoding to something compatible with `vi`.
- Add `set nocompatible` somewhere in your `~/.vimrc` (You can make the file if you don't have it). then restart your termninal.

The second solution has always worked best for me.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1159206/difference-between-vi-vim for differences between `vi` and `vim`

Comment: I'm not a big `vi` fan, but [according to this](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/5.1/postlfs/vimrc.html), character encoding and `set nocompatible` have nothing to do with what the `vi` command resolves to... Besides, setting `nocompatible` is said to "*stop `vim` from behaving in a strongly vi-compatible way*", which, in a way, is the opposite of what the OP seems to be looking for.

Comment: Someone had already helped OP with the original issue of `vi` linking to `vim`, so I was addressing different solutions to the 'ABCD' spam.  Which is why I immediately preceded the list with the quote stating his ABCD issue. Like I said, this should have been a comment on the original question instead of an answer, but this account currently lacks the reputation to post comments on any thread other than my own.

Answer (score 2):

Note in several Debian based distros the symbolic link in /bin/vi is to 'busybox' and not vim at all.  In some cases this can be OK but the features busybox provides are a minimum set and for some reason seem to vary on how busybox was compiled.

If vim is installed it usually replaces the busybox link -- but sometimes not so -- busybox may still be linked to /bin/vi while vim is linked to /usr/bin/vi -- so it will depends on the PATH environment variable on which is found first.   A typical user may get 'vim' but when logged in as 'root' get busybox vi.

Best to check and see which vi link you are using (which vi) and what that is linked to.

Comment: Might be helpful if you could add some examples how to query and manipulate/correct $PATH (or link to some related post like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/273909/how-do-i-manipulate-path-elements-in-shell-scripts for more details) and also show some examples for the symlinks you mentioned. @Costas provided some nice examples e.g. in http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/182693/#comment304241_182693